# Can find xpath of elements on Chrome but can't find it on Firefox

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've a xpath for input an email, it's: 
//input[@id='email_input']

I can find it on Chrome, but the problem is I can't find it on Firefox, and this's error I get when I try to run it "The server did not provide any stacktrace information".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo352.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zmhw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0dok.png)

I tried with Css selector, but the result is the same! So what problems am I getting with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Chrome screenshot, the pink drop down value on the toolbar, "*fancybox-frame150...*", shows the current iframe. You'll need to do the same in Firefox - there is a button on the right of the toolbar (refer to this [MDN doc on iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes)), select the same iframe and you should be able to find the element with the same selectors.

To work with the element in code, be sure to first switch to the frame before performing any action on it, e.g:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("fancybox-frame150"); //be sure to use the full name of the frame
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email_input"));

//to switch back to the main frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inspecting elements in chrome ,inspect those elements in firefox first using `firebug` and `firepath` which is an add ons in FF. If you aren't aware regarding how to capture elements in FF then refer [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) link. Let me know in case of any issues.